# Getting a sum from a while loop

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to get the sum of even numbers between 2 and a value entered by the user. I managed to get as far as printing out the even numbers but how would I get it to print just a sum of the even numbers? Rather than listing out all of the even numbers?

At the end it should look like this:

Entered value: 20

Sum of even numbers between 2 and 20: 110

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice_7_1
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 while (true)
 {
 //Gather data value
 System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
 int value = input.nextInt();
 String text = "Sum of even numbers between 2 and " + value + " is: "; 
 //Loop
 int i = 2;
 while (i <= value)
  {
  if (i%2 == 0){
     text = (text + i);
     if (i< value)
        text = (text + ", ");
     else
        text = (text + ". ");
   }      
  i++;
 }
 //Output
 System.out.println(text);
 }
}
}
```

Edit:
Final answer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice_7_1
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 while (true)
 {
 //Gather data value
 System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
 int value = input.nextInt();
 String text = "Sum of even numbers between 2 and " + value + " is: "; 
 //Loop
 int sum = 0;
 for (int i = 2; i <= value; i +=2){
  sum += i;

 }
 //Output
 System.out.print(text);
 System.out.println(sum);
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Why not use a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop. With a for loop, you can customize the "step" of your internal loop variable (`i`). This also removes the need to check for even-ness.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 2; i < value; i+=2) {
  sum += i;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

On a side note, you should probably avoid the use of `while(true)` because it's going to require the use of an explicit `break` to exit the program. You should instead use some sort of boolean control variable.

Comment: You could skip the useless first iteration by using the correct starting point.

Comment: I have the while(true) in there because the assignment wants it to run indefinitely. Will the above code find the sum only for the even numbers?

Comment: @khmer11 Yes. Since `i` is initialized to 2, and the step of the for loop is 2, `i` will only increment to even numbers.